# Leave event on Ext.form.Panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Is there any event triggered when the user tapped elsewhere outside of an Ext.form.Panel ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case you should listen to tap on area of component which is outside the panel.
You can listen to something that happens not something that doesn't happen.

Btw if your panel is modal window and somebody is tapping on masked part of viewport then you can hide it(if that's what you want) using hideOnMaskTap config: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Container-cfg-hideOnMaskTap